# VBA lookup with 2 dimensional table

Tags: arrays, vba, matrix, lookup

I have a large 2D table.  I want the user to make a selection for the 2 categories from drop-down menus and have a cell return back the intersecting value.

What's the best way to implement that?  Using vlookup(), .index, .match()?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

index and match (separately) are the best, as if you put the match (i.e. the lookup) in its own cell, you can use it again if you want to look up some other column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it:

Setting up some test data:

```
      1       2        3        4
  A  the      quick    brown    fox
  B  jumped   over     the      lazy
  C  dog      and      landed   on
  D  the      large    grazing  cow
```

Then in Cell B7, I set Data validation to List: `=$A$2:$A$5`
   (this allows us to choose A-D)
Cell B8, Data validation to List: `=$B$1:$E$1`
   (this allows us to choose 1-4)

Now you just need to convert the second choice to numbers if needed via MATCH, and do a VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($B$7,$A$2:$E$5,$B$8+1,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about vlookup + match :) ?  It's powerful and yields a fairly small formula which can save some headache if you deal with formulas all day.  I imagine you have something like what I have below (Thanks for the data set Ditto!), where A2 and B2 are your drop down selections.

[image]

Here is the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(myRow,myTable,MATCH(myCol,myColRng,0),0)
```

So instead of having a static number for the column index argument of the vlookup, you can return the number based on the match lookup.  Thus both column and row are searchable.

I made it look cute with named ranges which you may prefer to do:

Your two drop downs:

myCol = A2                 myRow = B2

Table and column ranges:

myTable = A4:D7    myColRng = A4:D4